# Does "open source hardware" only apply to controllers or to all components?

Tags: components, open-source

I'm new to the hardware world and am coming from a software background, and am trying to build a small device to attach to my PC via USB. I've heard the term "*open source hardware*" in reference to controllers/MCUs/CPUs, but was wondering if it can also apply to *any* hardware component, such as:

- Power Supplies
- Transceivers
- Motors
- LEDs
- Speakers
- RFID Scanners/Tags
- Motion Sensors
- Light Sensors

If not, then why? If so, then how does one tell an "open source" component, such as an "open source transceiver", from a closed source/proprietary one?

Comment: Anything can be open source if the maker makes it so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Open Source" means quite literally that the source is open.

In the context of software that means the source code.

In the context of hardware that means the schematics, PCB designs, BOM, etc are all freely available.

What the hardware may be is of no concern, only that the designs are "open".

As far as components are concerned - you can think of a component as a single statement in a program, such as "if" or "else" or "while".  You put those together to make a program in the same way you put the components together to make a circuit.  It's not the components that are open source, but the finished design.

Similarly, "compound components" or "modules" could be open source, as these would equate to a "library" in programming parlance - a pre-written piece of code to do a specific job that you include into your program, but the source code is available for if you want it.

Comment: And such components included in the open-source design may or may not be themselves open source similar to a propreitary software library.

Comment: Yep. Just like programming on windows.  Nothing written on windows can be truly 100% open source unless it doesn't use a single system DLL, which are all close source.

Answer (score 2):

Open source hardware literally just means what it says on the tin: it's open source and it's a physical thing. Can be any electronics.

There are some nuances of course. Most open source hardware enthusiasts agree that in order for something to be proper open source hardware, you need to:

- Publish the full schematics and layout in a format that can be read with free tools
- Publish the full BOM
- Make sure all components in the BOM are actually available in the free market
- Publish any firmware or other software required to get the OSH project into a workable state

It's generally not necessary or even possible to make sure that every nitty gritty detail is actually open source. Sometimes it is necessary to use components that are essentially black boxes - like the Raspberry Pi applications processor for instance. The full documentation for that part is unavailable without a big NDA, but it's alright, because this is not deemed essential for the operation of the device. But in other cases this may be a grey area.

Comment: "The full documentation for that part is unavailable without a big NDA" - Correction: the full documentation for that isn't even available with an NDA - some parts just plain don't exist.

Comment: Thanks @user36129 (+1) - I assume by "BOM" you mean "bill of materials", or the comprehensive list of all materials/sub-components used to make the device? Also, most importantly, what about my last question? How could I determine if a particular, say, transceiver is open or closed source? Thanks again!

Comment: If it is an off the shelf product then the data sheet will say if it's open source or not.  If it's a single component, then open source is meaningless in that context.  Most OSHW will have CC-BY-NC on it (Creative Commons, Attribution, Non-Commercial)

Comment: @HeineyBehinds: yes, BOM means bill of materials. Also, like Majenko said, you can't drill down further than about one abstraction layer when talking about open source. A PCB is open source when the drawings, layout, BOM and firmware are freely published, but when you go one layer beyond and look at the PCB material, the components themselves, etc. it's a totally different story. I mean, where would it end? Listing the exact manufacturing process of the plastics used in a chip? This is fundamentally different from open source software, where you indeed can know *everything*.